# Testing ngModel in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a directive that creates some input fields and links them to the scope with `ngModel`. When the user of the directive creates this in the HTML file:

```
<div tk-quick-form="formStructure" form-data="formData" id="main_form" ></div>
```

and this in the controller:

```
$scope.formStructure = [
    {
        fieldName: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }
];
```

Then an input field will be created with `ngModel` linking in to `formData.name`.

The directive works as planned, but I don't know how to test for it in Jasmine.

This is what I'm doing so far:

Under the `it` function:

```
$rootScope.formStructure = [
    {
        fieldName: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }
];

var element = $compile('<div tk-quick-form="formStructure" form-data="formData" id="main_form" ></div>"')($rootScope);

$(element).find("input#name").val("set")
dump($(element).find("input#name").val()) // outputs "set"

expect($rootScope.formData.name).toBe("set"); //outputs Expected undefined to have value 'set' 
//(although in manual testing $scope.formData.name is actually set because the input field contains ng-model="formData.name")

$rootScope.$digest();
```

How should I write this test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for me you were doing everything right, except couple of things. You should have called `$rootScope.$digest()` before expect. Also, you have to trigger 'input' with `.triggerHandler('input')`, so model will get updated.

```
describe('tkQuickForm', function () {
    beforeEach(module('tkQuickForm'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.scope = $rootScope.$new();
        this.$compile = $compile;
    }));

    it('should pass dummy test', function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should link ng-model to formData', function() {
        this.scope.formStructure = [
            {
                fieldName: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            }
        ];

        var element = this.$compile(`
            <div tk-quick-form="formStructure" form-data="formData" id="main_form"></div>"
        `)(this.scope);

        this.scope.$digest(); // call digest first

        var input = element.find("input")[0];
        angular.element(input).val('set').triggerHandler('input');

        expect(this.scope.formData.name).toBe("set");
    });
});
```

Checked with `"angular": "~1.5.0"`. All specs are OK.

[image: Success]

[Related pull-request](https://github.com/tomklino/tkQuickForm/pull/1)

Comment: No, I actually already tried it and it didn't work. In my question it appears afterwards because I  tired moving that line in different locations in the code but that didn't help

Comment: @TomKlino then please share your directive's code. I'm curious what is going on :-)

Comment: I'm having trouble showing it in jsfiddle, but I just created a git repository for it here: https://github.com/tomklino/tkQuickForm (it does not include the tests yet as I don't like to publish unsuccessful attempts)

Comment: Ok. I will look what I can do

Comment: @TomKlino it would be nice to have already set test environment, even though tests would break.

Comment: @TomKlino by the way, what version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: @TomKlino see my updated answer. I have added triggering of `input` event with `.trigger('input');`. Please try it and tell me if it works